# Как правильно отдать HTML страницу с подключенными script и style

Tags: c#, сервер, httplistener

html страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="" id="dblist">
        ::dblist::
    </select>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="sidemenu">
                    ::tables::
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>::contentblock::</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

сервер делает так:

```
if (request.QueryString["showTable"] != null){
    html = File.ReadAllText("D:/HTTPServer/index.html");
    //формируется строка tbl с таблицей
    html = html.Replace("::contentblock::", tbl);
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    output.Close();
}
```

Если скрипт и стили записаны в коде страницы то все работает. Но если их подключить то не работает.
Запрос http://192.168.1.149:1111/script.js или http://192.168.1.149:1111/style.css не дает ответа. Чувствую что подход неправильный. Как правильно отдавать страницу?

Comment: А что вы отдаёте при запросах /script.js и /style.css ?

Comment: @nightflash я не знаю как отдельно обработать запрос на файлы. у меня все идет одной кучей в виде строки

Comment: Вам приходит не один, а три GET запроса, смотрите, какой именно файл просит браузер, его и отдавайте.

Comment: @aepot браузер просит `http://192.168.1.149:1111/style.css`   `http://192.168.1.149:1111/script.js`. отрезаю порт `File.ReadAllText(request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(":" + context.Request.Url.Port, string.Empty));` но все равно не видит файл